# Как переопределить стандартный интерфейс .NET-6?

Tags: c#, наследование

Стандартный метод [int IComparable.CompareTo(T? other)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.icomparable-1.compareto?view=net-6.0) допускает значение `NULL`.

Мне же нужно, для типов реализующих `IItem`, исключить проверку `(T is not null)`, так как кастомный `CompareTo([DisallowNull])` всегда принимает НЕнулевой аргумент.

Но компилятор выдает предупреждение о неверной реализации и подсвечивает ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```cs
interface IItem : IComparable<IItem> {
  // Пробовал так, но это тоже не помогает :(
  // public new int CompareTo(IItem other);
}

class Item : IItem {
  // Ошибка csharp(CS8767) ... не соответствует неявно реализованному 
  //  элементу "int IComparable<IItem>.CompareTo(IItem? other)
  public int CompareTo(IItem other) {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

Как *перекрыть* этот метод в `interface IItem /* ... */` и избавиться от предупреждений?

**UPDATE:**

Проблема заключается в отображении этой ошибки не только при компиляции, но и в окне "ПРОБЛЕМЫ", что очень мешает.

Вариант с "правильной" реализацией CompareTo(?)

```cs
interface IItem : IComparable<IItem> {
  public int Id { get; set; }
}

class Item : IItem {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int CompareTo(IItem? /* <- "?" надо удалить знак вопроса */ other) =>
    // ... и избавиться от этой строки (other is not null)
    (other is not null)
      ? Id.CompareTo(other.Id) // <- оставить только это
      : 1;
}

class Foo {
  public static void Test(IItem? foo) {
    IItem item = new Item { Id = 1 };
    IItem? itemNull = null;
    var _ = item.CompareTo(itemNull);
    //        Вот здесь -> ^^^^^^^^ <- никогда не будет NULL и мне нужно отобразить ошибку
  }
}
```

Comment: Ну вызывайте свой кастомный из стандартного. Переопределять уже готовые интерфейсы в наследниках без изменения самих интерфейсов не получится

Comment: Зачем это нужно? Как это будет использоваться?

Comment: @tym32167 Проблема не в вызове, а ошибке которая мешает. Добавил пример и не очень "хорошее" решение.

Comment: @aepot Добавил в вопрос пример "_как не надо_" и ниже(_в ответе_) указал пример "_как надо_".

Answer (score 0):

Вариант решения:

1. Перекрыть метод `new`
2. Подавить предупреждение в месте реализации с помощью `#pragma`

```cs
interface IItem : IComparable<IItem> {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  // 1 Перекрываю метод
  public new int CompareTo(IItem other);
}

class Item : IItem {
  public int Id { get; set; }

  // 2 Подавляю ошибку реализации
#pragma warning disable 8767
  public int CompareTo(IItem other) => Id.CompareTo(other.Id);
#pragma warning restore 8767
}

class Foo {
  public static void Test(IItem? foo) {
    IItem item = new Item { Id = 1 };
    IItem? itemNull = null;
    // 3 Теперь NULL указывает на ошибку - как это было задумано
    _ = item.CompareTo(itemNull);
    // csharp(CS8604)  ^^^^^^^^
  }
}
```

Это решает вопрос с переопределением стандартного `CompareTo(?)`, допускающего NULL.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но ... - Проблема в том, что везде придется указывать `#pragma`, хотелось бы этого избежать. Кроме того, я не знаю, может ли применение `#pragma` в отдном месте, "сломать" что-нибудь в другом.

Comment: Сокрытие метода работает только если у вас переменная вашего класса, попробуйте `IComparable<IItem> item = new Item { Id = 1 }` вот так переменную объявить и все по идее сломается.

Comment: @tym32167 _и все по идее сломается(c)_ Хмм, я тоже думал сломается, проверил, вызвалась `new` и никаких ошибок компилятора. Интересно и другое: если добавить явную реализацию `int IComparable<IItem>.CompareTo(IItem? other)`, вызов `List<IItem>.Sort()` выберет явную, а не `new`, хотя `List` содержит `IItem`. А если нет явной, выбирает единственную перекрытую.

Comment: @tym32167 Сообщение об ошибке вводит в заблуждение "_неявно реализованному элементу_(с)". По хорошему там должно быть сообщение вида: "Не совпадает с требуемой сигнатурой". На деле, никакой реализации нет, `new` - это и есть первая в иерархии функция, поэтому и `IComparable<IItem> item = new Item()` сломаться не может.

Comment: точно, я забыл, что эта фигня, по сути, свистелка для синтаксического анализатора и не меняет сигнатуру функции